# GWT SuperDevMode breakpoints not working

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ, and I'm trying to put a breakpoint in a class, sometimes it works, but sometimes it brings the debugger in the file `MyApp-0.js` and I have to debug cryptic generated javascript.

Is there a way to navigate with my breakpoints in the corresponding Java file?

I am using IntelliJ 13.1.2

And yes, my GWT module uses the super dev mode settings:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
```

edit:

Also yes, I'm using the Jetbrains javascript debugging plugin in the latest version of Chrome.

I can access my sourcemaps from my code server manually by going to the code server page... Using IntelliJ plugin I go to `http://localhost:9876/sourcemaps/MyApp/` and I see the source.

It'd be useful to see how the config should look like in IntelliJ maybe.

Comment: This should be possible if sourcemaps are created and loaded from the codeserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help unfortunately.

Comment: I think this changes on thing though. I can now open all my project files in Chrome with the source maps, whereas before I could just open a small subset of them. Don't know if your suggestion made that, but now I can.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most important differences between DevMode and Super DevMode is the environment that executes your code. JVM executes your GWT module in DevMode so the IDE can debug it like an usual Java application. The bad news about Super DevMode is that Chrome executes your GWT module, so the IDE does not know about breakpoints that you set in Chrome Dev Tools.
If your breakpoints in Chrome Dev Tools don't work properly, I think this is a bug that should be [reported](http://www.gwtproject.org/lifeofanissue.html).

Comment: No that is not correct. There ist a Plugin for eclipse https://github.com/sdbg/sdbg and also an intellij Idea feature, that connects to a chroe browser and make a remote debugging possible again.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach What is the name of that plugin?

Comment: I postet a link to that plugin in my other comment. I think it is not available in the marketplace yet, but you can use an update url.

Answer (score 3):

What are you using as your application server? You might have to specify the code server port somewhere in the application servers parameters as well.

Comment: For Jetty adding "-Dgwt.codeserver.port=9876" to the VM Arguments should work.

Comment: Doesn't change anything for me.