# Debugging in Eclipse GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging, gwt

Since yesterday I've been working on an existing GWT project. My problem however is that I can't debug in Eclipse. It simply won't break in my breakpoints.

I've seen other people with the same issue:

- [GWT 2.0 Eclipse Breakpoint Not Working](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/se2khbc5HeA)
- [Why when starting GWT in debug mode, my break points don't break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960670/why-when-starting-gwt-in-debug-mode-my-break-points-dont-break)
- [Why are my breakpoints ignored with GWT, Eclipse, and Java 1.6.0_14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022007/why-are-my-breakpoints-ignored-with-gwt-eclipse-and-java-1-6-0-14)
- [GWT SuperDevMode breakpoints not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408521/gwt-superdevmode-breakpoints-not-working)

And I've also looked at some tutorials:

- [GWT development mode in Eclipse](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/DEV/GWT+development+mode+in+Eclipse)
- [GWT Debugging](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/debug.html)

I've tried all kind of different things based on these sites, but none of them seem to work. Some things I've tried:

- using FireFox instead of Google Chrome
- using jdk1.8.0_72 instead of jdk1.7.0_79
- putting `gwt-dev-2.7.0.jar` at the top of my Classpath User Entries (instead of somewhere in the middle)
- Adding any combination of the following Arguments: `-bindAdres my.ip.adres`; `-gen my_path`; `-eclipse` (`-eclipse` isn't a valid argument btw..).

My current configurations:

**Main-tab:**

```
Project:
    user-testwar
Main class:
    com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode
```

**Arguments-tab:**

```
Program arguments:
    -logLevel INFO
    -port 8888
    -war C:\Users\...\user-testwar\target\UserTestWar
    -superDevMode
    -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}"
    -codeServerPort 9997
    my.package.gwt.udf.viewer.TestWarProject
VM arguments:
    -Xmx512m
```

**Classpath-tab:**

```
Bootstrap Entries:
    JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]
User Entries:
    gwt-dev-2.7.0.jar
    java - \user-testwar\src\main\
    gwt - \user-testwar\target\generated-sources\
    java - \user-jar\src\main\
    gwt - \user-jar\target\generated-sources\
  > user-testwar (default classpath)
        user-testwar
        Maven Dependencies
        gwt-user.jar
        gwt-codeserver.jar
        gwt-dev.jar
        validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
        validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

So, anyone has any (other) ideas to fix the debug issues with Eclipse and GWT?

EDIT:

When I put a breakpoint in our RemoteService implementation class it does break there. But the breakpoints of my widgets / pages in the user-jar project and in the main code of my user-testwar project (where I want to debug) are ignored..

Comment: If you want to debug SDM in Eclipse, you need the SBDG plugin. Otherwise you have to debug in the browser.

Comment: @ElHoss Thanks for the suggestion. I've installed the plugin. It still won't break though. :(

Comment: I use it and it work. You should mess around with it as You get it working.

Comment: @ElHoss Thank you very much! I've followed the video at http://sdbg.github.io/ and had to add a new Google Chrome configuration. Now it's working. If you want, you can add this as an answer so I can accept it. Once again thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to debug your GWT application in Eclipse and you are using SDM, you need the SBDG plugin.

The SDBG-plugin can be downloaded here: https://sdbg.github.io/

Otherwise, when using SDM, you have to debug in the browser.

Another solution is to use Intellij Ultimate edition, which offers a JavaScript debugger. You need the Ultimate edition in Fact that the GWT facet is not part of the Community edition.

**Update:**

Starting with version 3.0 of the GWT Eclipse plugin, the SBDG-Plugin is integrated into the GWT plugin and makes it quite easy to debug a GWT application.

Comment: What is exactly SDM?How I know if I have it?

Comment: If you are using GWT 2.7 or 2.8 you'll have SDM (SuperDevMode).

Comment: Oh Thanks. I'm using GWT 2.8. It is incredible that this tutorial [link](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/debug.html) does not explain that.

Comment: It's an open source project. Feel free to update the docs. ;-)

Comment: I'll will do it as soon as I have more experience with GWT. I started since one week ago :)

Comment: Im not sure but I will comment it. I installed GWT 2.8 and the SBDG is already there, only is neccesary to set up correctly as shown in the link above.

Comment: That's right. I think you are using version 3 of the GWT plugin.