# How can I debug a GWT project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, gwt

I have a GWT-Maven project and I want to debug it. I have not any Idea about debug in development mode or production mode. so I am giving some step which I did.

1. I deploy the war file on tomcat6 liferay server.
2. now I set a break point on server side(its work perfect)
3. when I set break point on client its not workig.

so is there is any way to debug GWT client on development or production mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debug GWT on tomcat using eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692795/debug-gwt-on-tomcat-using-eclipse)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359054/debugging-in-eclipse-gwt/35361642#35361642

Comment: guys I am able to debug server side code, client break point is not working. I dont know why ?

Comment: How were you able to debug server side code? I'm not able to debug it netiher. If I set a breakpoint inside Eclipse on it, it never breaks the execution.

Comment: Is there any specific server which provide real time debugging of GWT project?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm following you correctly, but GWT is compiled into JS. Take a look at sourceMaps, I believe that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the debugger of your browser. Chrome is best for this.

Launch your GWT app.
Press F12 to open developer tools.
Select "sources" tab
In the tree on the left open "Title of your page (xxxx.html)"
Below this you will see source maps with all your packages.
Open the java file you wish to put a breakpoint in and set a breakpoint using Chrome.

Doing client side GWT debugging in Eclipse is afaik not possible. But for me the Chrome debugger is more than enough.
I think IntelliJ can do client side debugging for GWT from whitin IntelliJ itself (for the paid version of IntelliJ).

Comment: In source there in no java file exist. only nochache displaying

Comment: To be sure : Are you using SuperDevMode ? Or the old DevMode ?

Debugging a deployed application is not possible. Must be running in SuperDevMode or DevMode.

Comment: I also maintain this in my question. that i deployed my war on server.

Comment: i dont know its a production or development mode.

Comment: Since you deployed a war this is not running in DevMode or SuperDevMode.

In this case you are unable to debug the client application. You can only debug GWT when running in SuperDevMode or DevMode.

Comment: yes this may be the reason but my project is GWT-Spring-maven project. is it possible to run on super dev mode

Comment: This is what I found quite interesting for debuging the application.https://github.com/sdbg/sdbg